# Detect if an image is negative

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean some chest X-ray data to feed to a CNN. In my dataset are currently many images where the bones are shown in white (higher pixel value than the background), like so:[image: xray bones positive]

While others show the bones in a darker color than the background, like this:[image: xray bones nagative]

Can you show me a way to label the two? I have no other external info about the image, though it can be assumed they are the same size (

Assuming they have the same size (about 1000x2000) and that the first row of pixels has more than 1 different values (i.e. is not a blank border), I've written this simple code to compare a middle-ish pixel to the top-left one (likely to be part of the background).

```
if img[0,0] > img[500, 500]: # if background lighter than center
        img = 255 - img # make the image negative
```

As you can see even from these samples I posted, this comparison is not always a good indicator (sometimes there is a halo round the background or pixel in [500,500] can be similar to background). Is there some more reliable other way to detect if an image of this kind is negative or not?

Consider that in the dataset are some images with very few details and shading, such as

[image: bad quality xray]

Comment: look at histograms. compare them. you'll see that they "lean" one way or the other. -- normalized of course, not "histogram equalization". that means linear mapping between min and max values. equivalent to picking the right "window", to use a tomography term.

Comment: You mean normalized as in contrast stretch? I tried it just now and unfortunately the "leaning" is too subtle and variable to make assumptions on that, I think

Comment: ok, next ideas: corner pixels (areas) are likely background, so compare those to the average or center of the image. -- ridges in the image, from bone surface... tight highpass filter and see which way the remainder leans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion from [Christoph Rackwitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602877/christoph-rackwitz), I get good result with this approach:

- Optionally normalize the image
- Extract corners from the image, more likely to be background (I considered just the top corners)
- Extract center from the image
- Compare the regions with a threshold (fixed or average greyscale value of image), obtaining list of truth values
- Compare amount of pixels above the threshold (in percentage) to decide if background is lighter or darker than the center of the image: hence decide to invert the values.

```
def invert_if_negative(img):
    img = my_contrast_stretch(img)
    # assuming image has fixed size of (1396, 1676)
    # corners
    top_left  = img[:200, :200].flatten()
    top_right = img[:200, 1250:].flatten()
    # more or less center
    center    = img[1000:1300, 500:800].flatten()
    threshold = 120 # or computed from average
    top_left  = top_left > threshold
    top_right = top_right > threshold
    center    = center > threshold
    perc_white_corners = (sum(top_left) + sum(top_right)) / (len(top_left) + len(top_right))
    perc_white_center = sum(center) / len(center)
    if perc_white_corners > perc_white_center:
        img = 255 - img
    return img
```

```
def my_contrast_stretch(img):
    if img.dtype == np.float64:
        img = (img * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    M=np.max(img)
    m=np.min(img)
    res = img - m
    res = res * (255 / (M - m))
    return res.astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution involves **equalizing** the input image, then just **thresholding** applying a **fixed** threshold value. We can estimate the number of *white pixels* and compare against a threshold to decide if a correction needs to be applied.

Let's see the code:

```
# Imports:
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "RPWBn.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# Convert RGB to grayscale:
originalGrayscale = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Equalize histogram
grayscaleImage = cv2.equalizeHist(originalGrayscale)

# It might be interesting to you to check out the image equalization:
cv2.imshow("Image Equalized", grayscaleImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Binarize the image with a fixed threshold:
minThresh = 128
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, minThresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Compute the percent of white pixels:
(imageHeight, imageWidth) = binaryImage .shape[:2]
whitePercent = cv2.countNonZero(binaryImage)/(imageHeight * imageWidth)
```

Then, we check this value against a threshold, to see if we must apply the correction. You have the option to correct the original image and the equalized one:

```
if whitePercent > 0.5:
    print("Correcting images...")
    # Correct the original (unequalized) image:
    originalGrayscale = 255 - originalGrayscale
    cv2.imshow("Correction - Original Image", originalGrayscale)

    # Correct the equalized image:
    grayscaleImage = 255 - grayscaleImage
    cv2.imshow("Correction - Equalized Image", grayscaleImage )
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The second image is corrected. Here are the images for both possible results:

Original inverted:

[image]

Equalized inverted:

[image]

Now, in addition to the image inversion, you might need to do some additional post-processing to improve the brightness and contrast of the original. We can achieve this using the CLAHE method. Let's post-process the original, unequalized image:

```
    # Improve the brightness + contrast of the original image via 
    # CLAHE. 
    # Gray to BGR conversion:
    originalGrayscale = cv2.cvtColor(originalGrayscale , cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    # Conversion to LAB:
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(originalGrayscale, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

    # Split the channels:
    l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)

    # Apply CLAHE to L-channel:
    # You might need to fiddle with the parameters:
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=7.0, tileGridSize=(1, 1))
    cl = clahe.apply(l)

    # Merge the CLAHE enhanced L-channel with the a and b channel:
    limg = cv2.merge((cl, a, b))

    # Conversion from LAB to BGR:
    final = cv2.cvtColor(limg, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
    cv2.imshow("Original Corrected and Enhanced", final)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the enhanced image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this doesn't work: many images end up with a very similar whitePercent even when they are of opposite negativity, even when adjusting minThresh.

Comment: I'm going to ask here since you have been kind enough to answer me: does histogram equalization affect the performance of a future CNN I'm going to test this data with? I think it really helps in visualizing washed out images, but I'm not sure it will benefit the performance of the neural network